# Reading a textfile using scanner/reader/bufferedreader to read numbers in .txt-file

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files

I'm trying to write a small program in java, that'll calculate surface are and volume of a sphere, based on the radius of the sphere. These radii comes from .txt file with a single column of numbers.

I've tried searching a bit for this:
[Reading numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878316/how-can-i-read-numbers-from-a-file-in-java)

The code example looks a bit complicated for me as I'm not yet comfortable and experienced in reading java code. I've also tried reading this one:

[Opening and reading numbers from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806062/how-to-open-a-txt-file-and-read-numbers-in-java)

I get confused of the 'try' keyword, among other things, what is it there for?

Where the second example says `File("file.txt");` Do I put in the path to my text file?

If anyone can point me to a tutorial that'll take a beginner through these things, I'd very much like to know.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
```

// This class reads a text file (.txt) containing a single column of numbers

public class ReadFile {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String fileName = "/home/jacob/Java Exercises/Radii.txt";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName);

}
```

}

Best regards,

Jacob Collstrup

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small, simple snippet:

```
Scanner in = null;
try {
    in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\rrr.txt"));
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        int radius = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        System.out.println(radius);
        // . . .
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error reading file!");
} finally {
    if(in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

A `try-catch` block is something used in Java to handle **exceptions**. You can read all about them, and why they are useful here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

---

Of course, if you are using **Java 7** or above, the previous code can be simplified using something called `try-with-resources`. This is a another type of `try` block, except this will automatically close any "autocloseable" streams for you, removing that ugly `finally` section of the code:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\rrr.txt"))) {
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        int radius = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        System.out.println(radius);
        // . . .
    }
} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error reading file!");
}
```

You can read more about `try-with-resources` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

The `rrr.txt` file should just have a single number on each line, something like this

```
10
20
30
```

Comment: I tried the second part of your suggestion, after I had tried to make sure I understood what it was doing. It works very well!! Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to call it from another program to use the data there.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `try/catch` and finally are the ways for handling the `Exceptions` or `Errors` (as both **extends** `Throwable Class`) which arises while performing some work.

**Eg:** File I/O, Network Operation etc.

```
Scanner in = null;  

try {

    in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\rrr.txt"));

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {

  int radius = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());  // If this is     
                                                 // not an integer
                                                 // NumberFormatException is thrown.
        System.out.println(radius);


    }

} catch(IOException ex) {

    System.out.println("Error reading file!");

} catch(NumberFormatException ex){

    System.out.println("Its not an integer");
}
 finally {
    if(in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```